# Django не видит путь к фотографии, если название на русском

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Добрый день! Столкнулся с проблемой, когда `Django` не может увидеть путь к картинке, которая подписана на русском. Если же англ/цифры, то все работает нормально.

Вот часть кода:

```
if callback_data.find('L') != -1:
            mes = str(user.fish.NameFishRus)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)
            try:
                photo = open('/home/fishbot/fishbot/' + user.fish.Fish_photo.url, 'rb')
                bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
            except:
                pass
            mes = 'Введите длину в сантиметрах:'
            bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)
```

В моделях обычная модель `ImageField`
Пробовал еще такой способ сделать :

```
import urllib.parse

if callback_data.find('L') != -1:
            mes = str(user.fish.NameFishRus)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)
            try:
                photo = open(urllib.parse.quote_plus('/home/fishbot/fishbot/' + user.fish.Fish_photo.url, 'rb'))
                bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
            except:
                pass
            mes = 'Введите длину в сантиметрах:'
            bot.send_message(chat_id, mes)
```

Использую `Django 1.11`
Прошу помощи :) Спасибо!

Comment: Наверное, проблемы с кодировкой. Не могу придумать решение проблемы, так не вижу где она кроется. Могу посоветовать только загружаемые файлы переименовывать, например делать транслитерацию, либо снимать хеш с названия файла (если надо могу скинуть пример такого кода)

Comment: А зачем использовать url?  Используйте user.fish.Fish_photo.path для получения пути к файлу на диске.

Comment: Скорее всего не получается правильно подставить url в путь, потому что строка url закодирована с помощью percent encoding https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding